# Continue upload with GTLServiceTicket in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-drive-api, background-process

In the singleton responsible for network, I create an instance of drive service:

```
self.service = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc] init];
[self.service setShouldFetchInBackground:YES];
```

At some point I create a ticket to upload the given file:

```
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileHandle:fileHandle MIMEType:kGDriveMimeType];
GTLDriveFile *newFile = [GTLDriveFile object];
newFile.title = @"123";

// keep the file inside event folder
GTLDriveParentReference *parentFolder = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
parentFolder.identifier = parentFolderId;
newFile.parents = @[parentFolder];

GTLQueryDrive *uploadQuery = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:newFile uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

GTLServiceTicket *serviceTicket = [self.service executeQuery:uploadQuery completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveFile *uploadedFile, NSError *uploadError) {
    if (completionHandler) {
        completionHandler(uploadedFile, uploadError);
    }
}];

[serviceTicket setUploadProgressBlock:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, unsigned long long numberOfBytesRead, unsigned long long dataLength) {
    CGFloat progress = (CGFloat)numberOfBytesRead / (CGFloat)dataLength;
    if (progressHandler) {
        progressHandler(progress);
    }
}];
```

The whole problem is that when I'm downloading data using `GTMHTTPFetcher` the work in the background is continued. With uploading with `GTLServiceTicket` it is paused while the app is in the background. I cannot find any property to make it woking in the background. Am I missing something? How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any suitable solution with `GTLServiceTicket` so I've finished up with custom wrapper which is listening to `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and using `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:`.